# Heroku Java SpringBootApplication - Parameters

Tags: java, heroku, parameters

I'm just a beginner and I'm trying to create a server application with Java on Heroku. Therefore I'm using this [example](https://github.com/heroku/java-getting-started.git).
Can anyone tell me how I can read parameters from the request?
For instance when someone sends a request /db?reset
I know, that I could create an own handler for /reset in this example, but I extended this example and need to read parameters.

Kind regards,
hobber

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer on my own:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}")
public String id(@PathVariable("id")Long id, Map<String, Object> model) {
  // id can be used like a normal variable and also can have other types (String,...)
}
```

For a full example look at this [java-spring-sample](https://github.com/heroku/java-spring-sample/blob/master/src/main/java/com/springsource/petclinic/web/OwnerController_Roo_Controller.aj)